# How to get feature importance in xgboost by 'information gain'?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, machine-learning, xgboost

we can get feature importance by 'weight' :

```
model.feature_importances_
```

But this is not what i want. I want by importances by information gain.

we can get feature importance by 'gain' plot :

```
xgboost.plot_importance(model, importance_type='gain')
```

However, I don't know how to get feature importance data from above plot. Or

if there is function like `model.feature_importances_` to give gain feature importance? Either of the two ways will work. Please let me know in comments if the question is not clear

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can get it from

```
model.booster().get_score(importance_type='gain')
```

http://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/python_api.html

Comment: model.get_booster().get_score(importance_type='gain') working for me....Looks like it got updated

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I am a bit unclear about your question but still I'll try to answer this.

I guess you need something like feature selection. If I am right, then you can check sklearn.feature_selection.

Following is the URL:
http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_selection.html

There are many important functions like chi2, SelectKBest, mutual_info_classif, f_regression, mutual_info_regression, etc..

Comment: question is not about feature selection. It is simply about feature   importances that we get from model. Usually we get it based on f-score or weight. But i want the one based on 'information gain' from trees

Answer (score 0):

In the current version of Xgboost the default type of importance is `gain`, see `importance_type` in the [docs](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/python_api.html?highlight=get_score#xgboost.XGBClassifier).

The feature importance can be also computed with `permutation_importance` from `scikit-learn` package or with `SHAP` values. You can read details on alternative ways to compute feature importance in Xgboost in [this blog post](https://mljar.com/blog/feature-importance-xgboost/) of mine.